# kaminari with ror to pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

i am trying to pagination with kaminari for first time and i got error:

```
views/store/index.html.erb where line #23 raised:

undefined method `current_page' for #<Array:0x3ebe0c0>

Extracted source (around line #23):

20:     </div>
21: </div>
22: <%end%>
23: <%= paginate @buildings %>
```

controller>buildings_controller

```
def index
    @buildings = Building.all.page(params[:page]).per(1)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @buildings }
    end
  end
```

store>index

```
<%= paginate @buildings %>
```

what i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `all` in

```
@buildings = Building.all.page(params[:page]).per(1)
```

Like this

```
@buildings = Building.page(params[:page]).per(1)
```

And you are good to go.
The ActiveRecord `all` method returns an array, and i believe Kaminari don't expect an array to work.

Comment: thx for the help but actually is not working. after that gives me more and more error like the .per anw i have change the hole thing and now is working

Answer (score 0):

i have change the kaminari and i have use will_paginate and working like crazy!

in gemfile

gem 'will_paginate', '>= 3.0.pre'

in dash=> bundle install

in store>index

```
<%= will_paginate @buildings %>
```

in controller> store_controller

@buildings = Building.paginate :page=>params[:page], :order =>'created_at DESC', :per_page=>1

and done! your good to go with paginate